# How to understand the work flow in a particular database

Tags: sql-server, database

I have recently gotten a dot net code for analysis which has an underlying database of 100 or more tables, even more views and procedures. When I am analyzing the front end code, it's easier for me because I can apply break points and run the application. However, analyzing the database standalone, I don't have the same liberty. Or do I? I want to know if there are easier ways than manual analysis of Database. This is not the first time somebody has gotten a black box code, I just want to ask the community if there are ways where I can understand the work flow in the database faster than manually analyzing it.

I hope I have correctly surmised my doubt here.

Thanks

Comment: I think there is some database diagrams in your database which is like a workflow of a module .

Comment: what if that is not present and we just have a blind code in front of us?